# How to order a query by a translated field using globalize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to order a query using a field which is translated with globalize2. The problem is that since stored in database and in an association I'm having lot of problems.

- Doing an include of the translations and ordering by `category_translations.name` doesn't work.
- I tried a default_scope but since it doesn't allow to use lambda or a block for the conditions I can't get it working unless I use this patch for ActiveRecord http://gist.github.com/81187
- I've tried with the `with_translations` defined in globalize2, however I get an error with this and I couldn't get it to work even without ordering.

I've something like that

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_uniqueness_of :name
  has_many :products, :dependent => :destroy

  translates :name
end
```

The question is, how do I order by the translated name?

Answer (score 13):

The `with_translations` method seems to be way to go:

`Category.with_translations(I18n.locale).order('category_translations.name')`

Also, if you are using PostgreSQL you might want to add case insensitive order to that:

`Category.with_translations(I18n.locale).order("LOWER(category_translations.name) ASC")`

More about this here:
https://github.com/globalize/globalize#scoping-objects-by-those-with-translations

Answer (score 1):

I tested this using sqlite3, and it works.

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  named_scope :ordered, lambda {|locale|
    {
      #:select => "categories.*, categories.name sort_name",
      # For MySQL
      #:select => "categories.*, IF(category_translations.name IS NULL, categories.name, category_translations.name) sort_name",
      # For sqlite3
      :select => "categories.*, (CASE WHEN category_translations.name IS NULL THEN categories.name ELSE category_translations.name END) sort_name",
      :joins => ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize_sql_array([
        "LEFT JOIN category_translations on category_translations.category_id = categories.id AND category_translations.locale = ?", locale]),
      :order => "sort_name"
    }
  }
  ...
end

Category.ordered(some_locale).all # Returns all records, sorted by translated name
```

Comment: Of course being an INNER JOIN this assumes that translations exist for all categories. If not it'll need some tweaks.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, that's the first thing I tried, but since not all the translations exists that didn't solve my problem...

Comment: Had a bit more time for a test case, give this latest version a go. Hope it helps!

Comment: You didn't award your bounty. Was this not helpful?

Comment: You might want to stay on top of that, when people are generous enough to make time to try to help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that any model called `Category` would have at most hundreds of records if not less. Maybe you can consider sorting the results in memory, after fetching them.

```
@categories = Category.all # or whatever else to retrieve what you want
@categories.sort! { |a,b| a.name <=> b.name }
```

Beware though. This would become a bad idea if the `categories` table contains more than thousands of records.

Comment: Already thought about it... but I was looking for a more general mechanism since anything should be ordered, not just Category :(

Comment: @msc the bang version modifies the array in-place. You will get an error if that can't be done for any reason.